# React component doesn't re-render when state changes

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I am making a react app in which a user can input the identifier for an airport, and the app will get the respective weather data from a web API and display it in a table (ex: CYOW --> http://avwx.rest/api/metar/CYOW). I have gotten to the point where the 'url' state which specifies the API endpoint of the airport the user searches, is updating when they input the value, however the component is not re-rendering when that state changes and therefore my table is not updating. What am I doing wrong here? Sorry for the terrible code, this is my first go at React + JS. Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Icon, Label, Menu, Table, Form, Button} from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class Stationsearch extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            url: 'http://avwx.rest/api/metar/CYOW',
            data: {},
            Station: '',
            Timestamp: '',
            Time: '',
            FlightRules: '',
            Temperature: '',
            Dewpoint: '',
            Visibility: '',
            WindDir: '',
            WindGust: '',
            WindSpeed: '',
            WindVar: [],
            CloudList: [],
            Raw: '',
            userInput: '',
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        fetch(this.state.url)
        .then(d => d.json())
        .then(d => {
            this.setState({
                data: d, 
                Station: d.Station,
                Timestamp: d.Meta.Timestamp,
                Time: d.Time,
                FlightRules: d["Flight-Rules"],
                Temperature: d.Temperature,
                Dewpoint: d.Dewpoint,
                Visibility: d.Visibility,
                WindDir: d["Wind-Direction"],
                WindGust: d["Wind-Gust"],
                WindSpeed: d["Wind-Speed"],
                WindVar: d["Wind-Variable-Dir"],
                CloudList: d["Cloud-List"],
                Raw: d["Raw-Report"],
            })
        })
    }

    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({userInput: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event){
        this.setState({url: getUrl(this.state.userInput)});
        event.preventDefault();
    }

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Field>
                    <Label>Station ID</Label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="ex: CYOW" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </Form.Field>
                <Button type='submit'>Search</Button>
            </Form>

            <Table celled striped textAlign="center" color="teal" key="teal" inverted className='table'>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Type</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Value</Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Station</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.Station }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Timestamp</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.Timestamp }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Zulu</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.Time }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Flight-Rules</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.FlightRules }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Temperature</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.Temperature }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Dewpoint</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.Dewpoint }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Visibility</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.Visibility }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Wind-Direction</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.WindDir }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Wind-Speed</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.WindSpeed }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Wind-Gust</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.WindGust }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Wind-Variable-Dir</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ this.state.WindVar }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>Clouds</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{ getCloudString(this.state.CloudList) }</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Body>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )}
}

function getCloudString(cloudList) {

    var list = "";

    for (var i=0; i < cloudList.length; i++){
        if (i+1 < cloudList.length){
            list += cloudList[i][0] + " " + cloudList[i][1] + ", ";
        }
        else{
            list += cloudList[i][0] + " " + cloudList[i][1];
        }
    }
    return list;
}

function getUrl(stationID){
    var url = 'http://avwx.rest/api/metar/';
    var id = stationID.toUpperCase();
    url += id;
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you expect is to make another `fetch` request when the `url` changes.  In your current code, you only do a `fetch` inside `componentDidMount` which only is called once when your component is first created.  Instead, you should call it when the `url` changes, either in a `componentDidUpdate` method, or inside `handleSubmit`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However, when I put it in a handleUpdate() function, the values in the table flicker for a second before stabilizing, and when putting it in the handleSubmit() function, I have to press enter twice to get it to change. Any idea why this is happening? I'm assuming its because the values arent changing synchronously?

Comment: If you put it in `handleSubmit` you will need to make sure the state has changed before you do the fetch.  You can do this by doing it in the setState callback:

`this.setState({url: getUrl(this.state.userInput)}, () => { do the fetch here })`

Did you try calling it inside `componentDidUpdate`?  If so make sure you only call fetch when the url changes, by comparing the previousState url to the new state url.

Comment: @Ukranianolo are you sure a flicker is occurring take a look at the sandbox that i have created. I don't see flicker or I have to press enter twice. I think since api is taking time to fetch data you are having that impression. Try once enter station id and press enter only once it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is working now! Yes I will make sure to handle the invalid input. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are only updating the URL in the state of the component but not fetching data for that station id. After updating station id you also need to fetch the data and update it in the state. Your component was getting re-rendered but since any data was not changing, your view was not getting updated.

```
  fetchData = () => {
    fetch(this.state.url)
      .then(d => d.json())
      .then(d => {
        this.setState({
          data: d,
          Station: d.Station,
          Timestamp: d.Meta.Timestamp,
          Time: d.Time,
          FlightRules: d["Flight-Rules"],
          Temperature: d.Temperature,
          Dewpoint: d.Dewpoint,
          Visibility: d.Visibility,
          WindDir: d["Wind-Direction"],
          WindGust: d["Wind-Gust"],
          WindSpeed: d["Wind-Speed"],
          WindVar: d["Wind-Variable-Dir"],
          CloudList: d["Cloud-List"],
          Raw: d["Raw-Report"]
        });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({ url: getUrl(this.state.userInput) }, () => {
      this.fetchData();
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Here is the link to the working code. I have made default station id as OMDB and when you search for CYOW data gets updated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/3mqp187w1

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now. However can you please explain what the syntax means for the handleSubmit function you changed? I am new to javascript.

`handleSubmit(event){

        this.setState({url: getUrl(this.state.userInput) }, () => {
            this.fetchData();
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }`

Comment: The change was that a new callback was given to the `setState` function, fetching the new information. `setState` is actually asynchronous, so we can't try to access the state right after calling it, **unless** you do it through the callback that the function takes.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine, you're just not fetching again when you submit!

This is a working version:

https://codesandbox.io/s/k902vrw7k7

Also make sure to validate the user input, since as it right now you'll crash when they input an invalid station.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.